# How do I fix a "ReadOnly" in vb.net when using arrays

Tags: vb.net

It gives me an error message when i try to assign the Words array values from the text file. It tells me that words is"ReadOnly"

This is located in the sub "LoadWords"

```
Module Module1 

    Const MaxNoWords As Integer = 10000 
    Const MaxTries As Integer = 6

    Sub Main()
        Menu()
    End Sub

    Sub Menu()
        Dim words(MaxNoWords) As String
        Dim MenuChoice As Char
        Console.WriteLine("Hangman v2")
        Do
            MenuChoice = GetMenuChoice(MenuChoice)
            If MenuChoice = "a" Then
                LoadWords(words(MaxNoWords))
            ElseIf MenuChoice = "b" Then
                PlayHangman()
            End If
        Loop Until MenuChoice = "x"
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function GetMenuChoice(MenuChoice As Char)
        Console.WriteLine(" A - Load Words" & vbNewLine & " B - Play" & vbNewLine & " X - Quit")
        MenuChoice = Console.ReadLine
        Return MenuChoice
    End Function

    Sub LoadWords(ByRef words As String)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Words")
        FileOpen(1, "U:\A Level Computing\words.txt", OpenMode.Input)
        Do
            words(index) = LineInput(1)

        Loop Until EOF(1)
        FileClose(1)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub PlayHangman()
        Console.WriteLine("Playing Hangman DO NOT Disturb")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: you give a string to your LoadWords sub, but you try to access the "other" words (the array), but this array is not visible from within your function. you have to declare a words array (maybe mod_words) in your module header, not in your Menu() sub

Comment: As a "side-note" to your question... If you're going to use, and tag, code as `vb.net` then it would help to use it, instead of `FileOpen(1,`, `EOF(1)`,`FileClose(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this ...

```
dim mod_words(MaxNoWords) as string

Sub Main()
    Menu()
End Sub

Sub Menu()
    ' removed line
    Dim MenuChoice As Char
```

and later

```
Do
    mod_words(index) = LineInput(1)
Loop Until EOF(1)
```

Further I would suggest to use FreeFile (get free file handle) into a var, so you are not fixed to "1".

And somehow I do not understand, why yo try to add only at the last item in your array ...

Could you please explain, what exactly you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to load each word from the file (each on its own line) into the array called `words`.

If so, simply change:

```
Sub LoadWords(ByRef words As String)
```

To:

```
Sub LoadWords(ByRef words() As String)
```

Notice the addition of parenthesis, which indicates an Array, not a single string, is being passed.

*Also, ByRef is not necessary here, you could change to ByVal.

Comment: If doing that, then `LoadWords(words(MaxNoWords))` should be changed to `LoadWords(words)`.

Answer (score 0):

Explanations and comments in line.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Const MaxTries As Integer = 6
    'Moved words to Module level so it can be seen from
    'all method in the Module
    'Changed from array to List(Of String)
    'so we don't have to worry about the size
    Private words As New List(Of String)
    Public Sub Main()
        Menu()
    End Sub

    Sub Menu()
        Console.WriteLine("Hangman v2")
        Dim MenuChoice As Char
        Do
            MenuChoice = GetMenuChoice()
            'Also check if list is empty - you don't want to keep loading words
            If MenuChoice = "a" AndAlso Not words.Any Then
                LoadWords()
                'Check if the list has word, can't play without words
            ElseIf MenuChoice = "b" AndAlso words.Any Then
                PlayHangman()
            End If
        Loop Until MenuChoice = "x"
    End Sub

    Function GetMenuChoice() As Char
        Console.WriteLine(" A - Load Words" & vbNewLine & " B - Play" & vbNewLine & " X - Quit")
        Dim MenuChoice = CChar(Console.ReadLine.ToLower)
        Return MenuChoice
    End Function

    Sub LoadWords()
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Words")
        Dim path = "U:\A Level Computing\words.txt"
        'Use the .net IO methods instead of the old vb methods
        words = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList
    End Sub

    Sub PlayHangman()
        Console.WriteLine("Playing Hangman DO NOT Disturb")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```